# Clarification of speed control

Tags: control, fan, speed

Please could I know if the diodes in EESE question [“Control speed of Nidec fan”](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34346/control-speed-of-nidec-fan?rq=1) ARE zener diodes (as the symbols sugest) or normal diodes as on another article they had the exactly the same circuit but in the component list the diodes were given as 1N4148 (norma diodes) Thanks.

Comment: ......... What?

Comment: Crystal ball error 404: Unable to access "Control speed of Nidec fan". (in other words: please supply us with enough information to enable us to give a meaningful answer.)

Comment: Edited in the link to the base question located by pjc50.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you mean [Control speed of Nidec fan?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34346/control-speed-of-nidec-fan?rq=1) and the schematic in its accepted answer: 
[image]

I read those symbols as Schottky diodes (low forward voltage); while I've not analysed it in detail, I believe that replacing them with normal diodes will only slightly limit the max and min duty cycle.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I suppose the best way to verify is, at this point, is to build the circuit and test it.

Comment: They are definitely schottky diodes.

Comment: I agree with Connor. Schottkys make sense in this circuit, although a fast-recovery diode can work too. Zeners have single-break bars rather than the curlies from the Schottkys.